# Read session variable using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, session-variables, httpurlconnection

I am trying to log in to a website using an **HttpURLConnection**.

If the login is successful, the server sets `user_id` variable in the current session.

Using SO and the [Google developer docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#download) on the matter I have been able to POST my credentials to the server, but how do I get the user_id from the session now?

For reference here is my code:

```
String body = "user=chris&password=geheim";
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(LOGIN_URL).openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);

conn.connect();
OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

out.write(body.getBytes());
int response = conn.getResponseCode();
String s = "";
for (int c = in.read(); c != -1; c = in.read()) {
    s += (char) c;
}
System.out.println(response);
System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(conn.getHeaderFields());
```

*Note: to make it easier to read I've left out all exception handling and resource management. Also this is just trial code connecting to my localhost, so no worries about the hardcoded credentials and other insecurities.*

### Update

Okay, apparently my body is not getting submitted after all. When I do a `console.log(util.inspect(req.body))` in my server code, it prints `{}`. I double-checked the request method and that is POST. What am I doing wrong?

*Rewrote the code, and even though I think I did the exact same thing as before it's working now. Weird, but whatever.*

Comment: How does server sets the user_id? It it being set in the cookie? What does `System.out.println(response);` and `System.out.println(conn.getHeaderFields());` print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session where the `user_id` is stored, is kept on the server. All the client usually gets is a session-id in a session cookie (e.g. JSESSIONID) that is passed back to the server so the server can find the correct session and data again.

That's why you also can put large amounts of data into a user's session ... imagine all of that was actually passed to the client!

Comment: Okay thanks, that makes sense. What is good practice for offering remote clients (think Android app) a way to log in then? Offering an extra login url for non-browser logins? Or maybe using the regular one and encoding the login result in the response header?

Comment: Both ways are possible. An extra login would also require a completely different setup of the services. The server would be stateless and the client would have to pass the user_id (and additional parameters) with every request. So if you already have a server-side application it might be better to go along with the existing system, meaning to fetch the session-id from the login-response and put add into every further request's header (e.g. as a cookie)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am currently developing the server-side application, I have an existing Android app which I want to sync with it. From extensive googling, it looks like if I want to do this right, I should set up an OAuth 2.0 server, so I'm now looking into that. Unfortunately, not a lot of documentation out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless there is a co-operative active page in the server that will give it to you.